# map string to vector or map different keys to one value

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, unordered-map

I need to map a single string to multiple strings, to do this i thought about two different solutions:

The first is to map each string to a vector so that when i look at the key i get the vector in return. `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>`
Using this solution means that i need to look for a key only once but then i have to iterate on the array to find the correct string that i need.

The second solution i thought was to use each string contained in the vectors (i know that they are unique) as key and map them to what would've been the key in solution 1. `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>`
Using this solution means that i need to look for a key n times (where n is the length of the array in solution 1) and in my map i have the same value for many keys (i don't know if that matters in the end) but i would directly have the string that i need.

example 1:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> map;
std::vector<std::string> arr = {"hello", "world"};
map["greetings"] = array;
```

example 2:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map;
map["hello"] = "greetings";
map["world"] = "greetings";
```

For the purpose of my program it doesn't matter what string I have in the end (the value from the array of solution 1 or the value from solution 2) as long as I have a way to map them to each other so both solutions are viable.
I don't have a way to know in advance the length of the array in solution 1.

Are there any major differences in the two solutions? Which one would be faster/use less memory on paper?

Comment: I'm confused by your question, since the mappings go in opposite direction. What is your input: `"greetings"` or `"hello" and "world"`? Or do you need to be able to map both ways?

Comment: what about `std::unordered_multimap`?

Comment: @Angew it doesn't matter to me if the input is ```"greetings"``` or ```"hello" and "world"```, i just need to have them "connected" to each other.  A vector of pairs would work too but then i would need to iterate to find the correct one and i can't afford that time

Comment: You consider it a problem that you must iterate the vector when searching for a particular value. How does your example 2 help? How do you know that you've found the value that you're looking for? What can you do with the mapping when you find it?

Comment: @user2079303 that's my question, i don't know if my example 2 helps in any way. This map has to be accessed upwards of a couple million times so even saving 1 millisecond each search will impact the running time significantly. I was wondering if it made any difference in this sense having it one or the other way

Comment: What does accessing the map mean? What is your input and what is the output that you expect? The both examples that you show are completely different.

Comment: @user2079303 yeah it's pretty complicated to explain without discussing in detail what i need to do (i can't go into much detail). Let's consider this map as a table in a database containing the keys of 2 other tables, i don't care if i start from one key or the other since i know both tables but depending how this map is constructed i will be able to go only from one table to the other quickly but not viceversa (as i want). I don't know if that made it clearer or worse to understand to be honest xD, accessing as in "reading a value"

Comment: @JohnSmith if accessing as in "reading a value", how do you know which value you want to read?

Comment: @user2079303 you just made me realize how dumb i am, in real XY problem fashion i realized that what i'm doing before creating the map right now doesn't make sense in the context of the program. Apparently my brain just farted while trying too hard to think for a couple of days about how to fix a problem i created myself... I pretty much need to go from Z to A instead of from A to Z like i'm doing now and i won't incur into any problems. I feel stupid xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mapping between one string and a sequence of strings (or perhaps a set of strings, if the insertion order isn't significant). Let us call the former keys and the latter values, despite your second example using them in reverse manner.

Example one allows you to efficiently find all values associated with a particular key. Therefore approach one is faster and approach two is slower.

Example two allows you to efficiently find the key to which a particular value is mapped to. Therefore approach two is faster and approach one is slower.

As you can see both examples are faster than the other.

Comment: Well, you technically answered my question on which one is faster and made me realize my error so i guess your answer is the most correct

Answer (score 0):

Your two options do different things.

example 1:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> map;
map["greetings"] = {"hello", "world"};
map["farewells"] = {"goodbye", "cruel", "world"};
for(auto && pair : map) {
   for(auto && value : pair.second) {
      std::cout << pair.first << value;
   }
}

// greetings hello
// greetings world
// farewells goodbye
// farewells cruel
// farewells world
```

example 2:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map;
map["hello"] = "greetings";
map["world"] = "greetings";
map["goodbye"] = "farewells";
map["cruel"] = "farewells";
map["world"] = "farewells";
for(auto && pair : map) {
   std::cout << pair.second << pair.first;
}

// greetings hello
// farewells goodbye
// farewells cruel
// farewells world
```

Comment: yes but i know that all the strings are unique, hence i would never overwrite the value of a key like it happens in your second example. I.E. once ```"world"``` is mapped to ```"greetings"``` i know for sure that i won't have  ```map["world"] = "farewells";``` ever

Comment: Is it a bidirectional relation? have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

Comment: specifically `boost::bimap<boost::bimap::unordered_unique<std::string>, boost::bimap::unordered_non_unique<std::string>>` seems to fit your requirements